# Is there a way to make a screenshot of a component in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, picturebox

Is there a way to make a screenshot of a component in C#

I have a panel with graphics in there and I want to make a screenshot of this panel and display this screenshot in a picturebox.

So thanks a lot in advance for your support.

Comment: windows forms or WPF?

Comment: You might want to checkout Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Point upperLeftSource, Point upperLeftDestination, Size blockRegionSize)

Comment: Make sure the graphic is created in or triggered by the Paint event! Then the answers will work. If not, correct your code to do it right!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using windows form try using the Control.DrawToBitmap method and make sure the form has focus when you run the code.

```
Graphics gfx = form.CreateGraphics();          
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(form.Width, form.Height);
form.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, form.Width, form.Height));          
bmp.Save(fileName);
```

you can use `panel` `picturebox` or other control which is inherited from `Control` instead of `form`